# Blank Frontend & Backend

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Getting blank front and backend magento pages.  This happened after backup in magento the previous night.  Have tried to remedy with 
https://kb.magenting.com/content/22/38/en/magento-shows-blank-empty-page-how-do-i-solve-this.html

However, the problem is backed is not showing for me.  So then I tried from ssh but even as root I cannot make changes to files or run commands to disable compiler.

I also tried to edit files via sFTP but same issue with file system.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with hosting company.  They had failover issues which locked the filesystem to read only!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked Magento and PHP logs? You must be able to find out what is missing in those log files. In this case it seems to be a Fatal error which you likely can find the reason in the PHP logs.

If you are unable to edit files it is probably for writing permissions. Try *chown* + *chmod* commands to give writing permissions to the files you want to modify.

Comment: Any time I try to execute commands I receive back the error 'Read-Only file system.  I am not sure what has happened for it to suddenly have this behavior.

Comment: Im now also noticing that mysqld_safe is taking close to 100% cpu.